# Get IP address from one-to-one connection?

Tags: windows, networking, ethernet, ip-address

I have PC box with installed Windows Embedded which runs specific software and have no display and I can't connect one. It has stable ip address which was set years ago, but somehow it was lost by other admin and now I need a way to figure it out.

- I can connect to PC box with Ethernet cable
- I can get other network equipment like bridge, router (in future)

What options do I have to get this IP address?

Comment: Do you know at least the network on which belong this IP address?

Comment: @RomeoNinov No, unfortunately, network was completely reconfigured and this box left untouched. Company can't get in touch with previous admin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try connecting an Ethernet cable while [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) is monitoring the connection on your side. Windows does duplicate IP address detection, so as soon as the link is up you should see it send several ARP queries for its own IP address.

(Depending on configuration, it might even have NetBIOS enabled, which causes NBNS packets to be broadcast as well. Finally, at some point, you might see Windows Update traffic, if that was also left enabled.)

Comment: nice idea, I'll try